# Why doesn't PostgreSQL lookup by PK first (when `WHERE` contains more conditions)?

Tags: postgresql, index

When I run this against my PostgreSQL DB (where the `id` column on the `courses` table is the primary key, and there's also an index on `is_deleted`, which is a boolean):

```sql
SET enable_seqscan = OFF;

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT c.title
FROM courses AS c
WHERE c.id = 1 AND NOT (c.is_deleted)
LIMIT 1
```

This is the query plan:

```
Limit  (cost=4.15..6.17 rows=1 width=318) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on courses c  (cost=4.15..6.17 rows=1 width=318) (actual time=0.033..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
        Filter: ((NOT is_deleted) AND (id = 1))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 2
        Heap Blocks: exact=2
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_courses_is_deleted  (cost=0.00..4.14 rows=2 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=6 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (is_deleted = false)
Planning Time: 0.179 ms
Execution Time: 0.068 ms
```

Unless I'm misinterpreting this (which is entirely possible because I'm totally new to this), it's basically filtering by `is_deleted` FIRST instead of simply doing a lookup using the PK and its index. This doesn't make sense, wouldn't it be more efficient if it simply did a `Index Scan using pk_courses on courses`?!

Comment: Why? Because it thinks that's more efficient. Perhaps if you had more than 6 rows in your table, the access plan might be different.

Comment: Please don't ask [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77198174/6464308) in multiple fora.

Comment: In some databases this would happen if the estimate on the PK filter was 1 row, but the estimate on the is_deleted filter was 0 rows. Personally I think there is a great case for having a heuristic to prefer the PK and not using purely cost-based optimization. One of the postgres experts will probably answer with more pg-specific details.